# Error - model sent to the view is incorrect

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting following error message.Could somebody tell me why I am getting the following error message. My model is getting initialized with values when I debug the controller.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'AngularJSMvcExample.Models.RegistrationVm', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.
```

My model code

```
namespace AngularJSMvcExample.Models
{
    public class RegistrationVm
    {
        public string Courses { get; set; }
        public string Instructors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller code

```
namespace AngularJSMvcExample.Controllers
{
    public class RegistrationController : Controller
    {

        private RegistrationVmBuilder _registrationVmBuilder = new RegistrationVmBuilder();
        // GET: Registration
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_registrationVmBuilder.BuildRegistrationVm());
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewCode

```
@model AngularJSMvcExample.Models.RegistrationVm

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registration";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container" ng-controller="RegistrationController">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <span class="navbar-brand">Registration</span>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav nav-bar">
                    <li ><a href="/Courses">Browse Catalog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Instructors">Browse Instructors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My RegistrationVmBuilder code

```
namespace AngularJSMvcExample.Models
{
    public class RegistrationVmBuilder
    {

        public RegistrationVm BuildRegistrationVm()
        {
            var registrationVm = new RegistrationVm
            {
                Courses = GetSerialisedCourse(),
                Instructors = GetSerialisedInstructors()

            };
            return registrationVm;
        }

        public string GetSerialisedCourse()
        {
            var courses = new[]
            {
                new CourseVm {Number= "100", Name= "Physis", Instructor = "Jan"},
                new CourseVm {Number= "101", Name= "Chemistry", Instructor = "Sal"},
                new CourseVm {Number= "102", Name= "Biology", Instructor = "San"},
                new CourseVm {Number= "103", Name= "History", Instructor = "Jack"},
                new CourseVm {Number= "104", Name= "Maths", Instructor = "Rahul"}

            };
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
            var serializeCourses =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(courses, settings);
            return serializeCourses;
        }

        public string GetSerialisedInstructors()
        {
            var instructors = new[]
            {
                new InstructorsVm {Name= "Jan", Email= "jan.test@test.com", Roomno = "10"},
                new InstructorsVm {Name= "Pal", Email= "pal.test@test.com", Roomno = "9"},
                new InstructorsVm {Name= "San", Email= "san@test.com", Roomno = "11"},
                new InstructorsVm {Name= "Jack", Email= "jack@test@test.com", Roomno = "12"},
                new InstructorsVm {Name= "Rahul", Email= "rahul@test@test.com", Roomno = "15"}

            };
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
            var serializeInstructors = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instructors, settings);
            return serializeInstructors;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other partial views on the page being rendered ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the index view?

```
@model AngularJSMvcExample.Models.RegistrationVm

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Registration";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

 <div class="container" ng-controller="RegistrationController">

   <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="navbar-header">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <span class="navbar-brand">Registration</span>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav nav-bar">
                <li ><a href="/Courses">Browse Catalog</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Instructors">Browse Instructors</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is the index view

Comment: do you have any partial views or actions rendered any where in the _layout?

Comment: in the layout I saw a reference to @model string. When I removed that it works but however when I traverse to courses or instructors there is no data